# Laravel's "artisan vendor:publish" not publishing anything but returns "Publishing complete"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Today I installed Torann's GeoIP package for Laravel. The require me to run `php artisan vendor:publish` in the projects directory, so I could publish Torann's config file alongside my application's config files. When I execute it it returns "Publishing complete" however, nothing is actually published. The service provider IS added to `config/app.php`. I am using a shared hosting running Linux, if that matters. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Documentation says to run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPServiceProvider" --tag=config`, is this what you tried?

Comment: Yes, I tried the exact commands the documentation requires. I also tried running it with the `--force` flag, and also tried running `php artisan vendor:publish` for all packages. Same result.

Comment: As an alternative, you can copy the file manually: https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip/blob/master/config/geoip.php

Comment: But I will still not be able to use the artisan commands for the package (`php artisan geoip:update`) needed for the MaxMind database to download the files needed for work.

Comment: Seems various users already reported the issue: https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip/issues/105 and https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip/issues/87

Comment: This is where the package registers the publish command https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip/blob/948617dba3d9c2992c3b3ff48dbc429123000e58/src/GeoIPServiceProvider.php#L48

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPServiceProvider" --tag=config --force
```

Comment: Same result, I answered it in my comment following the question.